# $\nabla$ in curvilinear coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry, derivatives, calculus

I am trying to understand how the $\nabla$ operator changes whent the coordinates change (note that I have read other similar questions here and don't really understand what is happening):

In $x,y,z$ coordinates of course $\nabla f=(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x},\frac{\partial f}{\partial y},\frac{\partial f}{\partial z})$

Why then in cylindrical coordinates we have $\nabla f=(\frac{\partial f}{\partial ρ},\frac{1}{ρ}\frac{\partial f}{\partial θ},\frac{\partial f}{\partial z})$?

Ι really can't understand why the $\frac{1}{ρ}$ infront of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial θ}$.

I am familiary with the the chain rule and how to write $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ in other coordinates but this doesn't seem to help me.

*Question*: Can you explain how to go from the nabla from one set of coordinates to another? In particular from cartesian to cylindrical or to spherical.

Comment: Might [math.se] be better suited for this math question?

Comment: Related/dupe of: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/172606/25301, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/78510/25301, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41137/25301

Comment: You yourleft know the answer: use the chain rule. $\partial /\partial x =\partial /\partial r\cdot \partial r/\partial x $. However, mathematicians show it with a more beautiful and elegant concept: the **Jacobian**. You might want to read about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this is tagged with `differential-geometry` I'll follow a more geometric approach, if this doesn't suit, I am happy to tag this answer as `community-wiki`.

The computation you seek follows from the general definition of $\nabla$ on a manifold, $M$.

Thence
\begin{align}
\langle\nabla f(p)|v\rangle&=d_pf(v)\\
 &=\sum_i\left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}\right|_pdx^i(v)
\end{align}
Here, $p$ is a point in some manifold $M$, and $v \in T_p M$.

Summation here is over basis vectors of the tangent space. Expand this in order to find component $i$
$$
(\nabla f)_i=\frac{1}{k_i}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}
$$
Where $k_i$ is the modulus of the $i$th tangent vector.

Comment: Thanks very much ! Just to clarify, modulus is the norm right ?

Comment: @NickA. Yes, you are correct!